# I2C cabling rules for 2+ devices

Tags: i2c

I'm attempting to wire two breakout boards with i2c devices to a Mega2560:

- a HD44280 LCD with PCF8574 i2c backpack
- a combo board with DS1307 + AT24C32

There are two obvious possibilities for cabling:

- two 10-inch ribbon cables that come together right before connecting to the Arduino's SDA and SCL pins. Technically, one could be 6 inches... but I know that with RS485, you're asking for trouble if you do a star with branches of unequal length. The cables can't really be any shorter without seriously impairing my ability to debug it while partially disassembled (the LCD is mounted to the lid, and the cables are long enough to allow me to lay the lid on the desk next to the enclosure and power everything up without putting stress on the cables).
- Same 10-inch segments of ribbon cable, but daisy-chained... Arduino to LCD, LCD to RTC. In this case, the second one really needs to be 10", because it's mounted to the only clear spot inside the case I have.

Is one likely to be better or worse than the other?

Are there any rules about WHERE the pullup resistors have to go? The DS1307 module has built-in pullup resistors. Do I have to somehow disable them & use resistors right at the point where the bus connects to the Arduino's SDA & SCL pins, or can the pullups go pretty much anywhere on the bus (including at one end of a star, or at the far end of a daisy chain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I2C is generally slow. You don't have to worry about how to route the device connection. Because propagation delay won't be a matter. The main goal should be to minimize the capacitance of the wiring, which means minimizing the total wire length. But as you mentioned one of the cable lengths is fixed, then keep the other one to a minimum. The star topology will work if you keep the wire lengths within 10 inches.